# Swift: save text field in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, class

How to save the text of 2 textfields in an array?

This is what I tried. I use println to check if the values are in the array. But it seems it doesn't work.

Can anyone explain it and please, explain each step. Thank you

1- I create a swift file: novaClass.swift. I create an struct inside

```
struct novaClass {
    var img : String
    var text : String
}
```

2- ViewController.swift Declare an array

```
    var nouArray = [novaClass]()
```

3- save the text field in the array

```
@IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {

    //I put the text of 2 text fields in the array
    var nouText = novaClass(img: textField1.text, text: textField2.text) 
    nouArray.append(nouText)

    //I check the array
    println(nouArray) // this gives "[_.novaClass]" I do not understand

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check it by

```
println(nouArray[0].text)
println(nouArray[0].img)
```

Printing array as object will print its title only

Comment: Ok. This prints the content of the text fields. But only the first values. Can I check if the array gets all the values entered before? (till the app. was open of course)

Comment: Ofcourse now it prints first pait of values because its index in 0. You can check what you need by nouArray.count maybe

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behaviour in Swift. Swift objects don't have a description property by default, so `println` defaults to printing the class name.

Your class can adopt the `Printable` protocol (which have been renamed to `CustomStringConvertible` in Swift 2) to provide more detailed printouts:

```
struct novaClass: Printable {

    var img : String
    var text : String

    var description: String {
        get {
            return "{img: \(img), text: \(text)}"
        }
    }
}
```

Now try it:

```
var array = [novaClass]()
let x = novaClass(img: "foo", text: "bar")
let y = novaClass(img: "foo2", text: "bar2")
array.append(x)
array.append(y)
println(array) // will print: "[{img: foo, text: bar},{img: foo2, text: bar2}]"
```

Comment: I am very new in programming. I do not understand. You put that in the novaClass.swift, is that correct? and then how to check ?

Comment: @Nrc updated my answer with an example. Basically if you `println` your array, it will put there the result of `description` instead of `_.novaClass`